# Fetch all the folders in OneDrive using Microsoft graph API

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to fetch all the folders in Onedrive(not files) using graph api. I am looking for query similar to the below query:

```
var folders=await client.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

The above query fetches both files and folders and I am looking for folders only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the folders in the group there is a property called 'Folder' in every [drivenItem object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) which can be used to detect if that particular drivenItem object is a file or a folder. If that object is Folder then the value in it won't be null. If it is a file then definitely the Folder property is null.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<DriveItem>> GetOnlyFolders()
{
      var folders = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children
      .Request()
      .GetAsync();

       return folders.CurrentPage;
}
static void OnlyFolders()
{
      var result = GraphHelper.GetOnlyFolders().Result;
      foreach (var item in result)
      {
          if(item.Folder != null)
          {
               Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
          }
      }
}
```

Tested it in my application and resulted as below.

My OneDrive:-
[Please click this link to see my one drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOxuz.png)

My Application after applying the code:-
[Please click this link to view the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blq45.png)

Comment: How-to do authentication for OneDrive ? application or delegate for user ?

Comment: @Shiva Keshav Varma But this is returning 200 data. how to access next page?